# Python selection sort algorithm returns only a list of minimum value

Tags: python, selection-sort

```
def sortList(self, list):
    for i in range(len(list)):
        min = list[i]
        for j in range(i+1, len(list)):
            if list[j] < min:
                min = list[j]
        list[i] = min
    return list
```

The above algorithm returns a list the minimum value. For example, if the sample list is `list = [4,7,9,2]`, the algorithm will return `[2,2,2,2]`.

Where is the fault in the algorithm?

Comment: You write `list[i] = min`. Instead of shifting the other elements one to the right, you thus assign to that location.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the code to the above. The result is still the same

Answer (score 0):

Well there are some mistakes here:

1. first of all, you calculate `min` in a weird way, since you each time assign it to `list[i]`; and
2. you do not "swap" you simply assign the minimum to that part of the list.

What you basically need is an algorithm that each time calculates the minimum between `i` and the end of the list, and then either "shift" the other elements to the right, or perform a swap with the element that occupies the place where you want to put that element.

I think the latter (swapping) is a tiny bit more efficient, since it is an *O(1)* operation (but mind that finding the minimum is an *O(n)* opeation.

So you can use:

```
def sort_list(self,data):
    n = len(data)  # obtain the length of the list
    for i in range(n):
        min, minj = data[i], i  # we use data[i] as the running min
                                # i as index of the smallest item
        for j in range(i+1,n):  # iterate over the remainder of the list
            if data[j] < min:  # if we find a smaller item
                min, minj = data[j], j  # update min and minj

        # perform a swap between i and minj
        t = data[i]
        data[i] = min
        data[minj] = t
    return data
```

That being said *insertion sort* is definitely *not* the most efficient sorting algorithm, you better use the builtin `list.sort` method, or `sorted` function which are optimized for Python.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks.